# Difference between two get requests from Android Mediaplayer

Tags: java, android, proxy, get, android-mediaplayer

I am developing an application for extracting id3 tags from HLS live streams on Android. For this purpose, I have developed a proxy server which intercepts the data requested by the media player and performs id3 extraction. The media player requests are intercepted by the proxy server, the server relays the request to the remote server(the actual server hosting the media files), gets the response and sends it(as it is ) to the media player for playback. The problem I am facing currently is with two types of get requests from the media player:

GET /hls/live/segm14.ts HTTP/1.1 Host: arbitrarydomain.net Connection: keep-alive User-Agent: **stagefright/1.2** (Linux;Android 4.1.2)

This request is for an m3u8 file with [absolute urls](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2288/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40012238-CH1-TNTAG2) and is not being intercepted by the proxy

GET /live/fSequence0.ts HTTP/1.1 User-Agent: **Dalvik/1.6.0** (Linux; U; Android 4.1.2; GT-I8552 Build/JZO54K) Host: arbitrarydomain.net Connection: Keep-Alive Accept-Encoding: gzip

The above request is for an m3u8 file with [relative urls](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2288/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40012238-CH1-TNTAG3) and is intercepted by the proxy server

As you can see, both the **GET** requests are for .ts files. Only the **user agent** is different. So my questions are:

Does the user agent difference have any impact on the request?

Why does the first request come from stagefright(Android Native Media Framework) and the second one from Dalvik(VM)?

Is there a workaround for this(like forcing the media player for making a request from dalvik instead from stagefright)?